# What is this Kink in my GN curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to manipulate a Curve Circle in Geometry Nodes, by distorting the spline handles along the normals using a noise texture.

It works great except that I'm getting this kink, and I don't know how to fix it.

[Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgs21ctlecxljfh/Curve%20What.blend?dl=0)

[image]

[image]

Comment: i tried opening your file in blender 3.1 and 3.0 and it works fine without this kink.

Comment: I'm on 3.2.1.  Can you play with the Group Inputs in the GN Modifier?  There are some variations where the effect isn't as noticeable but for the most part it's there (for me).

Comment: yeah tried all settings . all good.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie: in 3.3 i can reproduce it - just open and you will see

Comment: if you change to nurbs or catmull rom, this will solve it

Comment: The [bug](https://developer.blender.org/T99850) has been fixed on July 25, 2022 with https://developer.blender.org/rB332d547ab7bc99604b31f20cb300a38277629787

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug. It is currently in the [`High priority queue`](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/) and broken since Blender version 3.2 logged as https://developer.blender.org/T99850

[image]

This issue is creating an unexpected result to the curve as shown in red circle.

[image]

Can easily be reproduced with 2 bezier circles plugged as *Object Info* into the *Curve To Mesh* node

[image]

The workaround is to plug the *Curve To Mesh* back to a *Mesh To Curve* then back again to a *Curve To Mesh* and plug the *Profile Curve* there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I call an exemplary, comprehensive answer :)

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you! :)

Comment: It honestly makes me pretty mad that something like this ends up in a stable release. Such bugs cost time and nerves, and sometimes I have the feeling that in *Geometry Nodes* you just apply some workarounds all the time, because this doesn't work and that doesn't work. ...I'm going to take a look at the new version of Houdini.

Comment: @quellenform: as a developer in my former life i can only say: don't believe that Houdini is without mistakes. Also developers make mistakes...and not only them, the quality people as well (which test/should ensure that it is bug free) are only human and there will be always errors in code written by human beings because we are not perfect. Maybe in a few years we have perfect software written by AI...and don't forget that GN is pretty new (for a software ;))

Comment: and i am very happy that you found a workaround which works and which is pretty easy to use....i have seen workaround for software problem which you won't believe.... :D

Comment: @Chris as a software developer too I can attest to exactly that :D

Comment: so quellenform, maybe start writing software...and you will see and learn :D but i can understand your frustration ;)

Comment: @Chris I've been developing software for many years, and I've learned a few things during that time: 1. write automated tests; 2. test every conceivable situation before making a new release; 3. implement new features only when there's a long-term perspective for them (to avoid changing everything again from release to release). ...just to mention the relevant points here. And yes, bugs can never be completely eliminated, and they do exist in Houdini too, of course, but you can and should expect that existing functionality will not get worse instead of better. Just mentioned.

Comment: @quellenform: yes, good points, but also automated tests can't cover everything. And as more complex the software is (and Blender is complex) as more possibilities are there to make mistakes. And although the "simple" tasks might be tested successfully doesn't mean that the complex ones will work. And also the automated tests are made from humans (who make mistakes in the tests as well ... and so on). It's an endless discussion ;) As long as humans are involved...the error rate will be pretty high ;) and never forget: it's still a free software. I know a software which costs millions...

Comment: ....and is much more full of errors than Blender is (3 big letters and the biggest software company in Europe)

Comment: bottom line is that as long as we don't remove the "thing" [between keyboard and chair](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK), we will always have imperfect software :D

Comment: Wow thank you for this answer. Life saver!  Also thanks for the stimulating discussion, I'm OK with bugs, especially when the community is strong enough to make heroes who come through with answers/fixes ;)