# Geometry nodes - Curve to Mesh Brakes UV of Entire Node Group Geometry

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

when Im using "Curve to Mesh" node, it brakes uv on entire model, even mesh that i'm not modifying in geometry nodes (i just joined it with "Join Geometry" node)
[image: i'm pressing M (mute node) on this gif]

[image]

Comment: if you are on blender 3.2 or 3.3, there's a known high priority bug with *Curve to Mesh* can you try this workaround here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269904/142292

Comment: on another note, i tried your file on blender 3.0, 3.1, & 3.2 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this a known issue.
https://developer.blender.org/T99915
For now, you can use two ways to bypass this issue:

1. Use "Geometry to instance" node
2. Use "UV map node" and define specific UV map
   [image]
   [image]